# Why do I get this error with auto-generated framework headers in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, operator-overloading, auto-generate

In my Swift code (in a Framework), I extend UIColor to support the multiplication and addition operators like this:

```
public protocol Interpolatable {
    static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Double) -> Self
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
extension UIColor: Interpolatable {
    public static func *(lhs: UIColor, rhs: Double) -> Self {
        var r = CGFloat(0), g = CGFloat(0), b = CGFloat(0), a = CGFloat(0)
        let t = CGFloat(rhs)
        lhs.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return self.init(red: r * t, green: g * t, blue: b * t, alpha: a * t)
    }
    public static func +(lhs: UIColor, rhs: UIColor) -> Self {
        var lhsR = CGFloat(0), lhsG = CGFloat(0), lhsB = CGFloat(0), lhsA = CGFloat(0)
        var rhsR = CGFloat(0), rhsG = CGFloat(0), rhsB = CGFloat(0), rhsA = CGFloat(0)
        lhs.getRed(&lhsR, green: &lhsG, blue: &lhsB, alpha: &lhsA)
        rhs.getRed(&rhsR, green: &rhsG, blue: &rhsB, alpha: &rhsA)
        return self.init(red: lhsR + rhsR, green: lhsG + rhsG, blue: lhsB + rhsB, alpha: lhsA + rhsA)
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly as expected in a playground or in a stand-alone project, but when I put it in a Framework the compiler generates this code in the framework header `MyFramework-Swift.h`:

```
@interface UIColor (SWIFT_EXTENSION(Animation))
+ (nonnull instancetype)*:(UIColor * _Nonnull)lhs :(double)rhs;
+ (nonnull instancetype)+:(UIColor * _Nonnull)lhs :(UIColor * _Nonnull)rhs;
@end
```

And this generated code produces this error:

```
error: expected selector for Objective-C method
+ (nonnull instancetype)*:(UIColor * _Nonnull)lhs :(double)rhs;
                        ^
```

(With the same error for the `+` operator)

I think this is only used to access the framework from Objective-C, because if I simply delete the contents of this header file my project builds and runs correctly.

Is this a wrinkle in Xcode or Swift toolchain, or am I missing something that I'm supposed to do when overloading operators like this? Note that I am interested in what the compiler is trying to do, and why this is a problem, not just a short answer to workaround or fix it.

Comment: Strange.  I don't think it should be including custom operators in Objective-C land at all...

Answer (score 4):

I eventually figured out what's going on and a proper fix for it.

**What's going on:**

When you create a Framework, it needs to be exposed as a module so that it is usable by other pieces of code. A lot of library classes (including `UIColor`) are actually Objective-C classes usable from Swift, so when you extend them the default settings make your extensions available in Objective-C as well. The compiler generates Objective-C headers for your framework, declaring your extensions as Objective-C methods, and in this case `*` and `+` are not valid method names in Objective-C, so it causes a compile error.

**The solution:**

To tell the compiler that you don't want these methods to be accessible from Objective-C, add `@nonobjc` in front of the method declaration.

```
@nonobjc public static func *(lhs: UIColor, rhs: Double) -> Self {
...}
@nonobjc public static func +(lhs: UIColor, rhs: UIColor) -> Self {
...}
```